# jsftp - error 425 can't open data connection even though i seem to get authenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ftp

I keep getting this error:

> { [Error: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of ""] code: 425 }

and I'm not sure why.  it authenticates as I get my message 'FTP authenticated for user etc.', but once I receive that message.. it pauses for a few seconds and then it inevitably I get that error message.  I've tried uploading too and I get the same thing.  And that index.html file exists on the main directory.  I'm using port 21 because my FileZilla seems to use it.  That's all the details I can think of.  Any help?

```
var username = 'someUserName';
var password = 'somePassword';

var ftp = new jsFTP({
    host: 'someHostHere',
    port: 21,
    debugMode: true
});

ftp.on('jsftp_debug', function (eventType, data) {
    console.log('DEBUG: ', eventType);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});

ftp.auth(username, password, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('FTP FAILED for user ' + req.user.username + '.');
        return res.send(false);
    }

    console.log('FTP authenticated for user ' + req.user.username + '.');

    ftp.get("/index.html", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR retrieving file');
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }

        console.log('success getting index.html');
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you transfer a file using a standalone FTP client on the same machine that runs the code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes i can

Comment: Do you know if FileZilla uses the `PORT` command for its file transfers?  As the [`jsftp`](https://github.com/sergi/jsftp/blob/master/lib/jsftp.js#L31) module does *not* appear to implement `PORT`, only `PASV`...

Comment: i'm honestly not sure.. I ended up using a different library and it worked just fine.  so something with the library.  thanks guys for trying to help